# American word for commode

Tags: vocabulary, slang, offensive-language, colloquialisms, euphemisms

I know several words for the toilet, i.e. bathroom. However I want to know the colloquial word for the seat on which one sits while defecating. I have read **john** somewhere but never heard an American actually use it in real or on TV. How common is the word in real? If not, what's the most commonly used word or words throughout the United States?

And while we're at it, is **commode** itself used commonly in American English? If not, what's the American non-slang equivalent?

P.S. I understand there are euphemistic alternatives such as *bathroom* or *lavatory* while referring to the act of defecating itself. My question, however, is more specific to the bowl and not the act. For example, consider this statement: "My bowl/commode/john/etc. is broken." One cannot use *bathroom* here. What's the word (or words) a typical **American** is most likely to use in this context?

Comment: americans say both john and commode, though commode is mostly used nowadays only by older people.

Comment: The seat is known as a "toilet seat".  It's attached to the bowl of a "toilet".

Comment: ("John" is slang.  "Commode" is rarely used, and may be mistaken for a reference to a piece of bedroom furniture.)

Comment: "Porcelain altar" is another one, although it's generally worshipped rather than sat upon.

Comment: @guifa And in the same situation, those of less religious proclivities might choose instead to [talk on the big white phone](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=talk%20on%20the%20big%20white%20phone).

Comment: In boot camp my first responsibility was “head” cleaning especially the commodes. It was the first time I'd heard the term. Wasn't the furniture type commode used to stash the chamber pot which served the purpose in the day?

Answer (score 7):

[Commode](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Commode): (from The American Heritage® Dictionary)

> - A low cabinet or chest of drawers, often elaborately decorated and usually standing on legs or short feet.
> - A movable stand or cupboard containing a washbowl.
> - A [toilet](https://www.google.it/search?q=toilet&biw=768&bih=928&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=4JVxVO_DF8TnatSNgYgB&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ).

[Toilet vs commode](http://www.waywordradio.org/toilet-vs-commode/):

> - Why do some folks call the toilet a commode? At one point in history, the commode was a piece of furniture you’d put a chamberpot in. **Today, commode is still a common term heard in the American South**. **Elsewhere, the term commode denotes a kind of cabinet,** causing confusion when journalists mistook reports of Congressman Randy “Duke” Cunningham taking a bribe in the form of a pair of [antique commodes](http://www.aim.org/media-monitor/in-the-toilet-again/)  worth more than $7000. What do you call your porcelain throne?

[Ngram - Toilet vs commode](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toilet%2Ccommode&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoilet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccommode%3B%2Cc0)

Why the Toilet is sometimes called a “[John](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/08/why-the-toilet-is-sometimes-called-a-john/) ”?

> - **The term is thought to derive from Sir John Harrington or, at the least, to have been popularized due to Harrington**. (There are a few references of the toilet being called “Cousin John”, as well as many references to it being called “Jake” and other such generic names, before Harrington was born; but it is generally agreed that why we now call it “John” is because of Harrington and not from the old “Cousin John”).

Toilet is the term you should use, commode has a restricted use though it is still common in some parts of US. John as well as other nouns are slang  [terms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/John?s=t)   and should be used with care. (See extract about "John" ).

Answer (score 4):

"Toilet" is the "official" US term for the thing upon which you sit, though occasionally "stool" is used.

See, for example, this page selling toilets: http://www.homedepot.com/b/Bath-Toilets-Toilet-Seats-Bidets/N-5yc1vZbzae

There are of course multiple slang terms -- John, throne, crapper, can,pot, etc.

"Commode" is sometimes used but it is also the name for a piece of bedroom furniture (one that was sometimes used to hold a bedpan or chamber pot, hence the connection), and one might therefore interpret the term as referring to furniture.

Comment: I'm an American who has never heard a toilet referred to as a *stool*. Stools are associated with milking, climbing, etc. (e.g. stepping stool). A completely different kind of stool is associated with the bathroom. Commode is still used: *bedside commode* is probably the most frequent example.

Comment: Stool is what goes into the toilet. A "stool sample" didn't.

Comment: "Stool" is a term that plumbers and carpenters often use, during house construction, etc.

Answer (score 3):

As several answers have noted in passing, Americans generally do not use *toilet* to refer to the **room**, unlike the French (and apparently others). For that they use *rest room*, *Men's room*, *Women's room*, *bath room* (typically at home, not public), or (old-fashioned, and for the *Women's room* only) *powder room*.

When Americans use the word *toilet* they mean what you sit on: the *toilet bowl* together with the *toilet seat* mounted on top of it.

In the US, the expression *go to the __ room* typically means to go to that room, but it sometimes is used as a euphemism for using the toilet.  The expression *go to toilet* unambiguously means using it.

Answer (score 2):

In the US:

The register of "toilet" is normal/neutral.

But Americans commonly resort to euphemism and would say "he's in the bathroom" or when in a public building "he's in the rest room". In schools they're often called "lavatories" rather than rest-rooms.  "She was caught smoking in the girls lavatory."

The register of "john" is casual, and while not offensive, it could be taken as an inappropriate familiarity.  It is fairly frequently used, in my experience, at least here in the northeast. "He's on the john."  Compare Elizabethan *jakes*.

Comment: I understand the bathroom or lavatory euphemism but my question is more specific to situations where I do need to refer to the bowl in which one defecates instead of the act itself. For example, "My bowl/commode/john/etc. is broken." What is the word an average American most likely to use here?

Comment: "Toilet" is the name of the device that the plumber fixes. It refers to the thing in its entirety, not just the bowl.  If you want to refer to the bowl (e.g. it is cracked) it is called the "toilet bowl".

Comment: And if you’re talking about broken ones, the most common thing to break is probably not the bowl itself, but the **cistern** that holds the water and most of the mechanics of the toilet. But whichever specific part is broken, the most normal thing to say when you’re calling the plumber would be, “Help, my toilet is broken.”

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - The toilet's water reservoir, in the US, is called the "tank".  Tell the plumber you have a problem with your "cistern" and he'll ask what sort of pump you have in it.